# When does the operator operand after the source address get used in an Access Control Entry

Tags: cisco, access-control-list

During my Cisco networking class I noticed something that confused me pertaining to extended access lists.

In the Cisco NetAcademy curriculum it lists this example of the syntax for an extended access-list:

```
**access-list** acl_number { **deny | permit | remark** } {protocol_name | protocol_number} source [ source_wildcard ] [**operator operand** ] [port port_number_or_name] destination [destination_wildcard] [operator operand ] [port port_number_or_name] [established]
```

My question is this: in what situations would you use the operator operand that directly follows the source / source wildcard in this above ACE example?

I have looked around in various places to find an answer, but as of yet I have not found one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is used when you need to compare tcp and udp port numbers.
Operator can be one of the following keywords:

- lt (less than)
- gt (greater than)
- eq (equal)
- neq (not equal)
- range (inclusive range of values)

and operand is the value of the source or destination port for the specified protocol.

For example, the following ACE:

```
access-list 100 permit tcp any host 192.168.1.1 eq 22
```

allows connections from any host to tcp port 22 (SSH) on host 192.168.1.1

And this one:

```
access-list 100 permit udp any eq 750 host 192.168.1.2 gt 1023
```

allows udp traffic with source port 750 and destination port greater than
1023 that originate from any host and is directed to the address 192.168.1.2

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So , here's a follow-up question.  In Packet Tracer when I set the following acl :

Comment: ip access-list extended DenyHTTP deny 172.16.64.0 0.0.63.255 eq 80 host 172.16.128.1 eq 80, Packet Tracer will allow the PC on the source network to contact the destination servers web page via the in program "web browser", but if I eliminate the eq 80 after the source wildcard the source network PC is blocked correctly. So, why does this happen like this? I would assume that if the source network PC is using a web browser that would fulfill the source eq 80 condition. Would appreciate a little more clarification on this.

Comment: When the web browser sends a packet to the server, the source port is selected randomly from the ephemeral range [http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65475/ephemeral-port-what-is-it-and-what-does-it-do] so the ACE `access-list extended DenyHTTP deny 172.16.64.0 0.0.63.255 eq 80 host 172.16.128.1 eq 80` doesn't match and the traffic is allowed. When you remove the option `eq 80` the traffic that originate from source network is denied, regardless of the value of the source port.

Comment: Ephemeral ports, that seems to be the missing piece to the puzzle. I may need to go back and review some old notes, but I think this is the first time I have heard that particular term. At least now I have that little mystery solved.